# Twitter Scraper, not showing result

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining

I'm a student and completely new to mining or scraping and my English not really good. I want to take a 'tweet' from a specific date. I followed a tutorial step by step, but in the end, the result were not shown. I am using google colab research.

Here's the code

[Installing twitterscraper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVB5S.png)

```
!pip install twitterscraper
```

[import library, add keyword and date, etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqC3b.png)

```
#Importing necessary files
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

#Providing the range of days in which I want the data 
begin_date=dt.date(2020,12,1)
end_date=dt.date(2020,12,10)

#Providing limit to the fetched tweets and also specifying the language of the desired tweets
limit=10
language='english'enter code here
#Extracting tweets for the Keyword “Covid-19”
tweets=query_tweets("covid",limit=limit,
                    begindate=begin_date,
                    enddate=end_date,
                    lang=language)'
```

`

[Creating Dataframe for the extracted tweets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCfmT.png)

```
#Creating Dataframe for the extracted tweets
df=pd.DataFrame(t.__dict__ for t in tweets)
df.head()
```

The result should be showing after 'df.head()', but it's not showing. And there's no error too. So why the result not showing ?.

I'm following tutorial from this site :
https://codehacks.in/twitterscraper-scraping-twitter-data-with-python/

Here's the image from tutorial :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tiwy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a9qC.png)

[this is the final result I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E89Jt.png)

this is the final result I expected

Before there is an error about the module can't found but it fixed when I saved the coding file in twittercrapper folder that I downloaded from the tutorial site

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: it would be easy for others to help you if you share code instead of image.

Comment: sorry, this is my first time posting question here. Thanks for the advice